# Why does the execution of the expression not stop (FireBase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I registered a code that indicates that the user has points on the balance that he can write to Reset. When writing to Reset, the number of points specified by the user is subtracted from the total number and recorded. Faced with the fact that the specified number of coins is written off without stopping.

Here is my code:

```
Button btn_res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_res);
    btn_res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int coins = Integer.parseInt(edCoins.getText().toString());
            if(coins < 1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Минимум 5000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle error: minimum conversion amount is 5000 coins
                return;
            } else {
                users.child(userID).child("coins").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        ucoins = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                        hashMap.put("coins",ucoins - coins);
                        users.child(userID).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Заявка записана", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                
                Reset newReset = new Reset(coins);
                mDataBase.push().setValue(newReset);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following reference:

```
users.child(userID).child("coins")
```

And you attach a ValueEventListener to it, it means you're listening for real-time updates. This means that every change that takes place in the Realtime Database that corresponds to the above reference, will always trigger the `onDataChange()` method. Since you are updating data inside the callback using:

```
users.child(userID).updateChildren(hashMap)
```

To the exact exact same reference you are listening to, your data gets written again. So this mechanism is happening over and over again, hence the behavior of an "unstoppable operation".

To solve this, simply change the above method call to [Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)):

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.

This means that it will listen for changes **only** once.

Comment: Hey ploxo. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?